# Считается ли нормальным обращение к свойствам или вызов методов по строковому эквиваленту?

Tags: javascript

Считается ли в js нормальным обращение к свойствам и вызов методов по строковым эквивалентам или этого лучше избегать? Типа -

```
function Test(){
    //...
}

Test.prototype = {
    prop1: 10,
    prop2: 10,
    prop3: 10,
    getValue: function( name ){
        return this[name];
    }
};

var test = new Test( );
console.log( test.getValue( "prop" + "1" ) );
```

Comment: В зависимости от контекста. Если это удобно и понятно, то так точно парвильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, get/set стандартная практика для JS:

```
function Test(){
    this.attrs = {};
}

Test.prototype = {
    get: function (name) {
        return this.attrs[name];
    },
    set: function (name, value) {
       this.attrs[name] = value;
       return this;
    }
};

var test = new Test( );
console.log(test.set('foo', 'bar').get('foo')); // "bar"
```

Comment: @RubaXa, спасибо! А то в as3, из которого я пришел, так делать плохо.     
Динамически задаваемые свойства в разы медленнее, но в js я проверял, доступ одинаков быстр. Вот только было сомнение "правильности", которое Вы и развеяли.

Comment: В JS это чуть-чуть медленнее, чем прямое обращение через точку.